# Calculate salary based on timeframe in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set containing working hours of employees. The wage table contains different salaries per `EmployeeNumber`. When a new salary is added to the wage table for a particular employee it also contains the start date of that salary.

Using a left join in below's output it shows 2 salaries but I only want to calculate the salary based on Date (first column). Hence the right salary should be 18,77.

All help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT Cast([date] AS DATE)               AS Date, 
       en.number                          AS EmployeeNumber, 
       Cast([startwork] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartTime, 
       Cast([endwork] AS SMALLDATETIME)   AS EndingTime, 
       ew.salary                          AS Salary, 
       ew.startdate                       AS StartDateSalary 

FROM   [employeebeginendsummary] eb 
       LEFT JOIN employee e 
              ON eb.employee_id = e.id 
       LEFT JOIN employeegroup eg 
              ON e.employeegroup_id = eg.id 
       LEFT JOIN employeenumber en 
              ON eb.employee_id = en.employee_id 
       LEFT JOIN employeewage ew 
              ON eb.employee_id = ew.employee_id 
ORDER  BY date DESC
```

Output:

```
Date    EmployeeNumber  StartTime   EndingTime  Salary  StartDateSalary
2020-03-13  303 2020-03-13 06:00:00 2020-03-13 08:30:00 17,84   2020-01-06 00:00:00.000
2020-03-13  303 2020-03-13 06:00:00 2020-03-13 08:30:00 18,77   2020-01-27 00:00:00.000
2020-03-13  303 2020-03-13 08:50:00 2020-03-13 12:22:00 17,84   2020-01-06 00:00:00.000
2020-03-13  303 2020-03-13 08:50:00 2020-03-13 12:22:00 18,77   2020-01-27 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and_ the expected result - as formatted text, no images.

Comment: Ok I edit the post

Comment: @Luukv93 This is confusing. You said you want 18,77 salary but in output you've 17.84 records. You need to frame your question properly.

Comment: Yes and this is not the right salary, I need to determine salary based on Date and StartDateSalary

Comment: Date is the date a particular employee worked. So on 2020-03-13, employeenumber 303 worked from 6 - 8.30. Salary should be 18,77 because latest StartDateSalary is 18,77

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? You need to use `row_number()` function to get latest record based on date and filter on it.

```
select 
Date, 
EmployeeNumber, 
StartTime, 
EndingTime, 
Salary, 
StartDateSalary
from 
(
SELECT Cast([date] AS DATE)               AS Date, 
       en.number                          AS EmployeeNumber, 
       Cast([startwork] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartTime, 
       Cast([endwork] AS SMALLDATETIME)   AS EndingTime, 
       ew.salary                          AS Salary, 
       ew.startdate                       AS StartDateSalary,
       row_number() over(partition by EmployeeNumber,[date] order by ew.startdate desc) as rn
FROM   [employeebeginendsummary] eb 
       LEFT JOIN employee e 
              ON eb.employee_id = e.id 
       LEFT JOIN employeegroup eg 
              ON e.employeegroup_id = eg.id 
       LEFT JOIN employeenumber en 
              ON eb.employee_id = en.employee_id 
       LEFT JOIN employeewage ew 
              ON eb.employee_id = ew.employee_id 
ORDER  BY date DESC
)
where rn=1;
```

Comment: It's close to the answer. But the Salary should be calculated dynamically. Let's say Date is 2020-01-02, then salary should be 17,84

Comment: added `[date]` to `partition by`. Is that what you need? Which date are you looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly. But try this:

```
SELECT Cast([date] AS DATE)               AS Date, 
       en.number                          AS EmployeeNumber, 
       Cast([startwork] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartTime, 
       Cast([endwork] AS SMALLDATETIME)   AS EndingTime, 
       ew.salary                          AS Salary, 
       ew.startdate                       AS StartDateSalary 

FROM   [employeebeginendsummary] eb 
       LEFT JOIN employee e 
              ON eb.employee_id = e.id 
       LEFT JOIN employeegroup eg 
              ON e.employeegroup_id = eg.id 
       LEFT JOIN employeenumber en 
              ON eb.employee_id = en.employee_id 
       LEFT JOIN (select TOP 1 id, salary, startdate from employeewage order by startdate 
 desc) ew 
              ON eb.employee_id = ew.employee_id 
ORDER  BY date DESC
```

If you want the oldest date you can also remove desc.

Comment: It's close to the answer. But the Salary should be calculated dynamically. Let's say Date is 2020-01-02, then salary should be 17,84

Comment: The date on the select is from which table?

Comment: From employeebeginendsummary (eb)

Comment: So try to put eb.date >= ew.start and remove the top 1